# How to Make UIImagePicker full screen with popover controller for ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have seen other posts on this subject, but no valid solutions.  Surely this is possible!  I found one solution here that suggests presenting it from a container view controller.  The code for that is commented out in my method below.  This DOES create the fullscreen view, but the cancel/take photo buttons won't work then, and I can't seem to dismiss it properly.  Is there really no simple elegant solution to this???? Please help!  Here's my code:

```
-(IBAction)launchCamera:(id)sender
{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        //fullScreenViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        //fullScreenViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(768, 1024);

        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        //  Tried making the view full screen (or at least larger), but doesn't work...
        //popoverController.contentViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(384, 512);

        [imagePicker setTitle:@"camera"];
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

        //[fullScreenViewController.view addSubview:imagePicker.view];
        // change imagePicker to fullScreenViewController here for full screen:
        popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
        [popoverController setDelegate:self];
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could make the UIImagePicker work properly in full-screen, so I ended up using the AVFoundation framework to implement my own.